# manually expire cache using Russian Doll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, russian-doll-caching

i have a user which can have a lot of saved searches and a lot of tasks.  i'm caching them using the following

```
- cache user do
  - user.tasks.each do |task|
    - cache task do
      # do something with task

- cache user do
  - user.saved_searches.each do |search|
    - cache search do
      # do something with search
```

i've added the option to update the user, via `touch` option, whenever any of these records are updated.  the issue i want to clarify is this scenario:

i've updated a search which expires the cache for that search and in effect, the cache for user.  since the cache for user has expired, `user.tasks` will be executed.

is there a way to prevent this?

I'm thinking of adding a key to `cache user` and manually expire the cache which I've been doing before I used the `cache_digest` gem but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Check out my previous answer to a very similar issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194270/rails-cache-key-generated-as-activerecordrelation/15206742#15206742

Comment: if i read your code right, `user.tasks` will still be executed. moreover, it will always be executed so it's a worse option that the current code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the user's cache key for expiring the collections, you can use the latest updated_at of the collections, [as the Rails Guide on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) demonstrates. E.g.

```
- cache("user-tasks/#{user.id}-#{user.tasks.maximum(:updated_at).try(:to_i)}") do
  - user.tasks.each do |task|
    - cache task do
      # do something with task

- cache("user-searches/#{user.id}-#{user.saved_searches.maximum(:updated_at).try(:to_i)}") do
  - user.saved_searches.each do |search|
    - cache search do
      # do something with search
```

Comment: it's the same with using `cache user`, `user.tasks` will still be executed when one task is updated

Comment: Yes, which is probably what you want - you asked about not executing `user.tasks` when a _search_ is updated, which in this case it won't.

Comment: ah right.  sorry, this question has been asked 2 years ago.  although what you have may work, a big issue is it goes through all the tasks and saved searches everytime you hit that page.